# how to pull data from a sheet named as per value in the cell on a different sheet

Tags: excel, vlookup, excel-indirect, vba

I have a multiple sheets in a workbook for orders on a same format and it will keep adding. Sheet name will be order number.

I wants to create a Quotation sheet with a different format but same information from any order i want to print the quotation agaisnt.

i am looking for a code or formula help to pick the information from Order sheet as per number / name on the quotation sheet. i.e. every time i change the number in a specific cell it pulls information from respective order sheet only.

will greately appreciate your help 
Thanks

Naman

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed your sheet names are in A2:A4 (just `1`, `2` and `3`) of some 'other' sheet and the reference of the cell you wish to refer to is always `D6` (the value in B1 in 'other`, which can be changed):

[image: SO19078619 example]

The formula is B2 of 'other' (copied down) is:

```
=INDIRECT(A2&"!"&B$1)
```

My comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123795/dynamic-path-to-sheet-name-excel) question describes one way to make such links dynamic.