# Dynamic Path to Sheet Name, Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel work book with a sheet I use to cross reference external table names to their associated lookup tables 2 columns. The first column is a list of table names. The second column is a list of the tables associated lookup table. See image

[image]

The lookup tables are additional sheets in the same workbook. So I have 5 additional sheets called 'Table1_lookup', 'Table2_lookup', 'Table3_lookup', 'Table4_lookup', 'Table5_lookup'

I want to dynamically set the Lookup table names to it's associated sheet, so that if someone changes the sheet name, the cell in the 'LOOKUP_TABLE' column in the cross reference table above, will automatically update as well. is there a way to accomplish this with a simple formula? I've seem ways to hard code to the sheet name, but when the sheet name changes, the link is broken.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: with VBA you could use Sheet's `CodeName property` and than make a reference to the sheet name. That's just idea which could be useful while I still see some problems to provide anything more.

Answer (score 1):

Use a series of formulae such as:

```
=RIGHT(CELL("filename",Table1_Lookup!A$1),LEN(CELL("filename",Table1_Lookup!A$1‌​))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",Table1_Lookup!A$1)))
```